# How to change Bootstrap localization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm using `ASP.NET Core` with `Bootstrap` and I recently integrated the localization support following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx) documentation. The main problem is that the `Bootstrap` framework is even in the default language, how can I also set the `Bootstrap` locale based on the selected language of `ASP.NET Core`?

I need to change the `Bootstrap` localization because the form validation message are still in english if I select in `ASP.NET Core` the german language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple switch in bootstrap for localization.

Validation messages and strings are in English and you can replace them by using a library like [Ketchup Validator](https://github.com/mustardamus/ketchup-plugin) for custom validation messages.

Comment: There is no localization for bootstrap? How does the framework detect language? Honestly, I can not find anything on internet

Comment: Bootstrap is just a minimum front-end framework. It is not meant to resolve all issues with developing a website. It does not detect language nor it doesn't have localization features. Although there is not much of it to change as long as you are using it for an LTR language. The validation strings mostly come from JQuery.

Comment: So if I change the `JQuery` language it will affect `Bootstrap` too? Do you know how to achieve this without install any third party libs?

Comment: Changing the JQuery file is not a good thing to do. I recommend using another library just for localization issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages that the default jQuery validation plugin uses come from the data attributes that are added to form fields by ASP.NET Core. These validation messages are ultimately those that are set by the validation data annotations in your model types.

To localize those, you will need to make sure that your resource file can correctly translate them. In doubt, it’s probably better to specify the (default) messages explicitly, so that you can target them properly.

See the [documentation for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dataannotations-localization).